# The second verb of subject should be express according to number or not?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> He is a man who has a bad heart.

or

> He is a man who have a bad heart.

Which one is correct?

I tried to search *"He is a man who have"* and *"He is a man who has"* on Google but I got quite the same number of matched result, so, I'm not sure which one should be correct.

Comment: *I tried to search "He is a man who have" and "He is a man who has" on Google* -- When you search for `"He is a man who have"` on Google, Google may tell you `About 37,400,000 results`. When you see that, don't just simply trust it. Try to get to the result #50 (i.e. on the 5th page, if your browser displays 10 results a page), and you'll see that it's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The first phrase is correct. The verb *to have* in your sentence is conjugated in the third person singular because of *man*. The relative pronoun is your subject in the subclauses which refers back to *man*.

> He is a **man** *who* **has** a bad heart.

I am not sure how you got this confused, because the other subject *He* in the main clause would also require a third person singular verb. You don't use the form *have* for the third person singular, that form is used for *I, you, we* and *they*. Both of your subjects require a third person singular verb, there are no plural or first/third person subjects in your clauses.

However, grammatical concord (subject-verb agreement) can cause confusion in cases like this:

> - It is **he** *who* **has** done this.
> - It is **I** *who* **have** done this.

Sometimes people will get confused, or perhaps don't even notice, and put *has* in the second sentence as well even though the relative pronoun *who* refers to *I* which requires the first person singular form of your verb.

Comment: Wait, don't you mean to say the first phrase is correct?
Although, I suppose he switched the order of them when he mentioned them again after the block quotes. Rather disorienting situation.

Comment: @CrazyEyes Yes I indeed meant to say first sentence, but I now also see that the OP's post is rather confusing :P